# Process.Start() doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, io, process.start

I have program `pro1.exe` that reads from input file, calculates result and writes it to output file.
Now I'm writing program `test.exe`, that tests it on different tests (fill input, run pro1 using `Process.Start()` and compares output with supposed)

Problem is following: after executing `pro1.exe` output file is empty. However, if I run it manually, it writes to output file.

Here is code how I execute pro1:

```
    ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    processInfo.FileName = _applicationName;
    processInfo.ErrorDialog = true;
    processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

    Process proc = Process.Start(processInfo);
```

`_applicationName` is a full path to exe file.

in debug I see, that process is starting, and ending without errors.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is often caused by having a different [`WorkingDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory.aspx).  You likely need to set the `WorkingDirectory` property to match the executable's path.

Without this, when `UseShellExecute == false`, the working directory may not be the application's local path.